# Non white space characters cannot be added to content with XDocument and UPS API

Tags: c#, xml, ups

I'm trying to send a UPSAPI request in xml using xDocument. but for some reason im getting an error trying to even make the xml?? im getting the error:

*Non white space characters cannot be added to content.*

on the string builder itself, and at no particular area. so i dont know where its failing. Here is the code:

```
        var requestXml = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "yes"),
            new XElement("AccessRequest",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en"),
                new XElement("AccessLicenseNumber", "LICENCE"),
                new XElement("UserId", "USERID"),
                new XElement("Password", "PASSWORD")),

            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "yes"),
            new XElement("RatingServiceSelectionRequest",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en"),
                new XElement("Request",
                    new XElement("TransactionReference",
                        new XElement("CustomerContext", "Rating and Service"),
                        new XElement("XpciVersion", "1.0001")),
                    new XElement("RequestAction", "Rate"),
                    new XElement("RequestOption", "Rate")),

                new XElement("PickupType",
                    new XElement("Code", "01"),
                    new XElement("Description", "Daily Pickup")),

                new XElement("Shipment",
                    new XElement("Shipper",
                        new XElement("Address",
                            new XElement("PostalCode", "33706"),
                            new XElement("CountryCode", "US"))),

                    new XElement("ShipTo",
                        new XElement("Address",
                            new XElement("ResidentialAddressIndicator", ""), //GET from postObject
                            new XElement("PostalCode", "34221"), //GET from postObject
                            new XElement("CountryCode", "US"))), //GET from postObject

                    new XElement("ShipFrom",
                        new XElement("Address",
                            new XElement("PostalCode", "33706"),
                            new XElement("CountryCode", "US"))),

                    new XElement("Service",
                        new XElement("Code", "03")), //GET from postObject

                    new XElement("Package",
                        new XElement("PackagingType",
                            new XElement("Code", "02")),

                        new XElement("Dimensions",
                            new XElement("UnitOfMeasurement",
                                new XElement("Code", "IN")),
                            new XElement("Length", "20"),
                            new XElement("Width", "20"),
                            new XElement("Height", "20")),

                        new XElement("PackageWeight",
                            new XElement("UnitOfMeasurement",
                                new XElement("Code", "LBS")),
                            new XElement("Weight", "10")))))); //GET from postObject
```

**UPDATE:**

ok so eliminating most of the code i get the error:

*This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.*

with this:

```
        var requestXml = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("AccessRequest",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en"),
                new XElement("AccessLicenseNumber", "LICENCE"),
                new XElement("UserId", "USERID"),
                new XElement("Password", "PASSWORD")),
            new XElement("RatingServiceSelectionRequest", "this"));
```

which literally translates to this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
    <AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
           <AccessLicenseNumber>LICENCE</AccessLicenseNumber>
           <UserId>USERID</UserId>
           <Password>PASSWORD</Password>
    </AccessRequest>
    <RatingServiceSelectionRequest>this</RatingServiceSelectionRequest>
```

how is not correctly structured? Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't have multiple root elements.

Comment: Why don't you try removing sections of your xml until it starts running again.  That will help you narrow down which piece is causing the problem

Comment: @SLaks after removing the second root element i get "This operation would create an incorrectly structured document."

Comment: Yes; you also can't have multiple declarations.

Comment: @SLaks - ok your right i broke it down to find out the error is on the second new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "yes")); but i think UPSAPI requires that.

Comment: Then they're requiring illegal, meaningless XML, and you should complain to them.  Or they just want two valid documents concatenated, which is still wrong.

Comment: @Sam I am - Yeah i removed most of my code in my update. But as soon as i add another element it gives me an error?

Comment: @NeoSketo  well then remove the obsolete stuff

Comment: @Sam I am - yeah technically nothing is supposed to be obsolete because i have to post the whole original to UPSAPI. my guess is something in xDocuments syntax but i have no idea. i guess i could just break the xml down more until i have one element and see if i have that error

Comment: As SLaks said, an XML document must have one and only one root element.  Yours would have two, which is not allowed.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element.

Comment: yeah i see now. i thought it was just the declarations. but yeah UPSAPI requires both. so i will have to concatenate them in two separate XDocuments to post to  UPS. I'll post an answer one i figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XDocument doesn't allow multiple roots as stated above. But the UPS shipping API needs two roots one for licence verification request and another for calculation request. Therefore i had to separate the two into strings:

```
        //Licence verification:
        var accessXML = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("AccessRequest",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en"),
                new XElement("AccessLicenseNumber", "LICENCE"),
                new XElement("UserId", "USERID"),
                new XElement("Password", "PASSWORD")));

        //Shipping request:
        var serviceXML = new XDocument(    
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("RatingServiceSelectionRequest",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en"),
            new XElement("Request",
                new XElement("TransactionReference",
                    new XElement("CustomerContext", "Rating and Service"),
                    new XElement("XpciVersion", "1.0001")),
                new XElement("RequestAction", "Rate"),
                new XElement("RequestOption", "Rate")),

                new XElement("PickupType",
                    new XElement("Code", "01"),
                    new XElement("Description", "Daily Pickup")),

                new XElement("Shipment",
                    new XElement("Shipper",
                        new XElement("Address",
                            new XElement("PostalCode", "33706"),
                            new XElement("CountryCode", "US"))),

                    new XElement("ShipTo",
                        new XElement("Address",
                            new XElement("PostalCode", "34221"), //GET from postObject
                            new XElement("CountryCode", "US"))), //GET from postObject

                    new XElement("ShipFrom",
                        new XElement("Address",
                            new XElement("PostalCode", "33706"),
                            new XElement("CountryCode", "US"))),

                    new XElement("Service",
                        new XElement("Code", "03")), //GET from postObject

                    new XElement("Package",
                        new XElement("PackagingType",
                            new XElement("Code", "02")),

                        new XElement("Dimensions",
                            new XElement("UnitOfMeasurement",
                                new XElement("Code", "IN")),
                            new XElement("Length", "20"),
                            new XElement("Width", "20"),
                            new XElement("Height", "20")),

                        new XElement("PackageWeight",
                            new XElement("UnitOfMeasurement",
                                new XElement("Code", "LBS")),
                            new XElement("Weight", "10")))))); //GET from postObject



        //Combine the strings and POST
        var requestXml = accessXML.ToString() + serviceXML.ToString();
```

all works fine now.